# One link of a non-jekyll github page site not working. Is there any cache of something I need to delete (non-local)?

Tags: github, hyperlink, github-pages

So I need to put a specific file with some specific text (location-> .well-known/acme-challenge/filename) where .well-known is at the publishing directory/source, so that I can obtain my SSL/TLS certificate from LetsEncrypt. However, once I try to create this, ALL links work except username.github.io/.well-known/acme-challenge/filename. If I modify .well-known or acme-challenge parts, the links work. I don't know why this is happening. Is there some cache somewhere I need to delete? I've run the links on private no-cache, no-cookies browsers too, they don't seem to work.

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and all their linked pages.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, will check it out! @theTinMan